# SwiftyJSON multiple accesses of the same key

Tags: json, swift, io, swifty-json

I read a JSON from a file and I'm using SwiftyJSON for that.
My code is aware of the structure and will never access any wrong keys. However it will access some keys a big number of times (I hold there my app strings).

My question is should I convert my data structure to an array when I read the JSON or will SwiftyJSON object be good enough?

Comment: Why should you do some extra treatment ? Your Swifty Json object is enough

Comment: How big is a "big number of times"? Usually it isn't all that big.

Comment: Also we can't really tell you if the SwiftyJSON object is good enough. Good enough depends entirely on how you feel about your app. Test it out yourself and see if you are satisfied with the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'll have a struct that can serialize/deserialize to/from JSON or [String:AnyObject]

If your question is primarily driven by performance considerations I'd say that it is good enough until proven that it is not.